# Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula for $ [X,[X,Y]] = [Y,[X,Y]] \neq 0 $

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are $n\times n$ complex matrices, and that $X$ and $Y$ commute with their commutator:

$$ [X,[X,Y]] = [Y,[X,Y]] = 0  $$

According to the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff (BCH) formula one gets (Hall 2015, Thm. 5.1)

$$   e^X e^Y = e^{X+Y+\frac{1}{2} [X,Y]}.   $$

Is there a similar (closed form) expression known if we consider the weaker assumption $ [X,[X,Y]] = [Y,[X,Y]] \neq 0  $ ?

Comment: So, the BCH formula contains an infinite series of commutators as I guess you already know. When $[X,[X,Y]]=[Y,[X,Y]]=0$, the series terminates after 3 terms as you showed. If these terms $[X,[X,Y]],[Y,[X,Y]]$ doesn't vanish, then the series might continue. However, I guess your hope is that since $[X,[X,Y]]=[Y,[X,Y]]$ then they commute and $[[X,[X,Y]],[Y,[X,Y]]] = 0$ so that the series might terminate. However, you still have to check if $[ X, [X,[X,Y]] ]  = [X, [Y,[X,Y]] ] = 0$ which might not be the case. Otherwise, the series might continue.

Comment: The next simplest case is the second Theorem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula#Special_cases). It has *glorious* applications in physics!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the following first terms:
\begin{align}
Z(X,Y)& =\log(\exp X\exp Y) \\
&{}= X + Y + \frac{1}{2}[X,Y] +
\frac{1}{12}\left ([X,[X,Y]] +[Y,[Y,X]]\right ) \\
&{}\quad
- \frac {1}{24}[Y,[X,[X,Y]]] \\
&{}\quad
- \frac{1}{720}\left([Y,[Y,[Y,[Y,X]]]] + [X,[X,[X,[X,Y]]]] \right)
\\
&{}\quad +\frac{1}{360}\left([X,[Y,[Y,[Y,X]]]] + [Y,[X,[X,[X,Y]]]]\right)\\
&{}\quad
+ \frac{1}{120}\left([Y,[X,[Y,[X,Y]]]] + [X,[Y,[X,[Y,X]]]]\right)\\
&{}\quad
+ \frac{1}{240}\left([X,[Y,[X,[Y,[X, Y]]]]] \right)\\
&{}\quad
+ \frac{1}{720}\left([X,[Y,[X,[X,[X, Y]]]]] - [X,[X,[Y,[Y,[X, Y]]]]] \right)\\
&{}\quad
+ \frac{1}{1440}\left([X,[Y,[Y,[Y,[X, Y]]]]] - [X,[X,[Y,[X,[X, Y]]]]] \right) \\ &{}\quad + \cdots
\end{align}
Even if $[X,[X,Y]] = [Y,[X,Y]]$, the higher commutators do not vanish completely in general (find an example!). I don't see an easy finite sum.